# How to fix "unknown formatting trait `f`" when formatting floats?

Tags: rust

I want a formatted string with a float limited to two decimal spots. So I wrote this:

```
fn main() {
    let width: f64 = 0.0;
    let width_text = format!("Width: {:.2f}", width);
}
```

But I get an error:

```
error: unknown format trait `f`
 --> src/main.rs:3:42
  |
3 |     let width_text = format!("Width: {:.2f}", width);
  |                                          ^
```

How can I do this? Is there something I'm overlooking?

Comment: Canonical Q&A: [How does one round a floating point number to a specified number of digits?](/q/28655362/2189130)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need the `f` suffix:

```
let width_text = format!("Width: {:.2}", width as f64);
```

I'm assuming you are coming from a C/C++ background where you need to use `%f` when attempting to format a number with the `printf` family of functions.  This is necessary because the mechanism used by C functions to handle a variable number of arguments does not include any kind of type information; the type information must therefore be conveyed another way, so that information is put into the template string.

In contrast, Rust's `format!` macro does not need to be informed of the expression's type.  Rust handles this an entirely different way from C: all information except for the actual values to be formatted is prepared at compile time by the [`format_args!` macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.format_args.html), which makes use of formatting traits instead of actual concrete types.  The way `f64` is handled by this macro is not fundamentally different from the way that `i64` is handled, for example.

Answer (score -1):

The compiler determines the variable type of width from the variable type of `longer_lengths[]`.  Whether `longer_lengths` is a vector or an array, its type is known at compile time.

So, when the `format!()` macro is called, there is no need to pass the variable type of the `longer_lengths[]` to the `format!()` macro.

To see what width's type is, we have to see where `longer_lengths[]` is defined.

e.g., Here is one way that `longer_lengths[]` could have been defined:

```rust
fn main() {
    let longer_lengths: Vec<f64> = vec![3.5, 33.5];

    let width = (longer_lengths[0] + longer_lengths[1]) / 2.0;
    let format_string = format!("{width:.2}");

    println!("{format_string}");
}
```

Alternatively, `longer_lengths[]` could have been defined as an array slice like this:

`let longer_lengths: &[f64] = &[3.5, 33.5];`

The replacement line using an array slice would produce the same output, again with no need to modify the format!() line.

Had the `longer_lengths[]` been defined as an f32 vector, like this:

`let longer_lengths: Vec<f32> = &[3.5, 33.5];`

The output would be the same.  The compiler handles the formatting differences from f64 to f32.  In this case, with a 2 decimal fixed size, the output for f32 and f64 would be the same.

The casting using "as f64" is only needed if the final output is different from the definition for `longer_lengths[]`